# Loop not functioning in counter

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to do a `while` loop. But I am getting specific error that I have researched and tried possible solutions without any avail. Down below is my `code` :

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       while(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           cout << KanonKula << endl;
       }
       int a = 2;
       if(a == 2) {
           a = 3;
       }
    }
```

Update, upon comment from blaze the quotes was put around. but I am receiving the following compilation `errors` :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:4:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
      while(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                   ^
main.cpp:4:21: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
      while(int i=0; i<2; i++){
```

Comment: I don't see a definition of `KanonKula`. Perhaps you wanted a string literal there? Try `cout<< "KanonKula" <<endl;` (note the `"` around `KanonKula`).

Comment: Hello @Blaze i am recieving the following error upon that, it can be seen above in the reedeit

Comment: @Blaze Upon answer from buddy, everything got functioned. i needed to use for. Thank you for everything

Comment: No problem, glad we could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `while` with `for`.  It’s a different keyword.

Comment: this fixed the issue and the code is working functionally with blazes answer. thank you alot and for all the help i recievied

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of a `while` loop in C++ is :

```
while(condition) {
   statement(s);
}
```

And

The syntax of a `for` loop in C++ is :

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

So you can do one of the bellow :

> ***Try with `for` :***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       cout << "KanonKula" << endl;
   }
   int a = 2;
   if(a == 2) {
       a = 3;
   }
}
```

> ***2nd solution (instead of `for`) :***

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 2) {
    cout << "KanonKula" << endl;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `for` instead of `while`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cout << "KanonKula" << endl;
}
```

If you still want to use `while` :

```
int i = 0; 
while(i < 2) {
    cout << "KanonKula" << endl;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for a while loop is:

```
while(condition>) {
  // do something
}
```

With your current setup you want to use:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
  // do something
}
```

Also, note that you did not put quotation marks in your cout command. Do the following:

```
cout << "KanonKula" << endl;
```